# Remove a line if regex exists only in 1st column of each line in a csv file

Tags: sed, awk, regular-expression, data, csv-simple

I have the following comma-delimited data (spaces used for visual clarity):

```
 1 2014 23 2352 19.24 7.18
 1 2014 23 2353 19.78 4.65
24 2014 23 2354 20.26 25.34
 1 2014 23 2355 26.65 42.76
 1 2014 23 2356 27.34 56.356
 1 2014 23 2357 29.24 45.4
24 2014 23 2358 30.23 345.27
 1 2014 23 2359 23.23 345.21
 1 2014 24 0000 12.53 1.98
 1 2014 24 0001 7.24  12.3
24 2014 24 0002 15.68 90.8
```

I would like to remove only every line that starts with 24 
(or keep every line that starts with 1, either way).

So the desired output would be:

```
 1 2014 23 2352 19.24 7.18
 1 2014 23 2353 19.78 4.65
 1 2014 23 2355 26.65 42.76
 1 2014 23 2356 27.34 56.356
 1 2014 23 2357 29.24 45.4
 1 2014 23 2359 23.23 345.21
 1 2014 24 0000 12.53 1.98
 1 2014 24 0001 7.24  12.3
```

I have tried

```
sed '/24/d' (filename)
```

But that removes every instance of 24 throughout the file, like this (not desired!):

```
1 2014 23 2353 19.78 4.65
1 2014 23 2355 26.65 42.76
1 2014 23 2356 27.34 56.356
1 2014 23 2359 23.23 345.21
```

Comment: Use it with `^` (starting anchor): `sed '/^24/d' filename` or `sed '/^1/!d' filename` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `awk` (prints everything with `1` at the beginning of the line):

```
awk '/^1/{print $0}'
```

With `sed` (`-n` option to suppress printing of everything):

```
sed -n '/^1/p'
```

With `grep` (perhaps not the best choice for text processing, but good enough in this case):

```
grep '^1'
```

Comment: excellent, thank you! I especially liked the explanations.

Answer (score 1):

`grep -v ^24` to keep only lines that do not start with 24